# execute shell command with sudo in c program

Tags: c, shell, command-line, system, execute

What is the best way to execute this command: "sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep Accepted" inside my C program ?
I tried to use:

```
sprintf(command_result,"sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep Accepted");
```

But it didn't work obviously.

Comment: you can use system(); function, just give the command as i/p argument..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can execute the command with pipe

```
FILE *fp;
fp=popen(command_result,"r");
```

and then you can read the command output from the pipe `fp` like you read from files with `fgets()` or `fread()`...

BTW you can not execute sudo command if the password is required in the sudo command

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute the command with `sprintf()` you need `system()` atleast

fix:

```
sprintf(command_result, "sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep Accepted");
system(command_result);
```

Comment: Well it didn't work (although system is the right function of course), but I think maybe the sudo access is demanded. I don't know how to get it though ?!

Comment: nothing happened. As if I didn't put anything.
Well it works for commands that don't need sudo access, but with sudo there is a problem obviously :(